# Convert a given decimal string into a binary string(even number of binary digits) in Java

Tags: java, string, binary, converters

I want to convert a string into a binary string.

I have tried

```
String str = "123";
int foo1 = Integer.valueOf(str);
String strbinary = Integer.toBinaryString(foo1);
```

It is giving the correct result but it is not useful because the output I am getting is 1111011, but the desired output is 01111011.

Is there some other better way to convert string into binary?
I want it 0-padding, in my case for 0-padding I want it just an even binary string, doesn't want everytime 16 digit binary as in this case

```
 String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0')
```

Comment: What's wrong with the given output? That it's not padded? Just pad it yourself.

Comment: Also the code gives an error. I guess the first line should be `String str = "123";`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis....I do not want it to be of 16digits everytime... is there some other way?